# What commands are needed in the '~/.vnc/xstartup' file to run KDE Plasma 5 in VNC?

Tags: vnc, kde5, plasma5, kwin

I am trying to run KDE 5 in a VNC session and although I get application windows like `konsole`, `kate` etc the shell I need for the Start Menus, taskbar, desktop background etc is not present. This is my current `~/.vnc/xstartup` file.

I also get a message that `kwin_x11` keeps crashing and I should try another shell.
What additional commands are required to get the shell workiing?

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
# /etc/X11/Xsession
startkde &
```

Answer (score 1):

What I discovered in attempting to do this is that the Plasma DE is much to heavy to run over vnc. When I installed LXDE and used startlxde in the xstartup file, I got a good desktop that ran beautifully over vnc and provided a similar experience to the Plasma DE.

Answer (score 1):

In order to launch a plasma desktop over VNC, use the following command  :

```bash
dbus-launch startplasma-x11 # or startplasma-wayland
```